# jmdns.jar not working on android 4.0 or later

Tags: android, service, bonjour, zeroconf, jmdns

*jMdns* is a great java library to provide [zeroconf](http://www.zeroconf.org/)/[bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/) capabilities to your Android application.

I successfully using this in a project up until `Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich aka ICS`, once Android 4.0 devices were starting to be used more often I am facing application not working.

I have tested application in android 4.0 earlier, it show me list of *Discover Devices* but in android 4.0 or later it show nothing.

I've tested this demo "https://github.com/twitwi/AndroidDnssdDemo" on 4.1 but its not working.

I have written Below code based on suggestion mention in ["http://snctln.com/2012/08/03/jmdns-and-android-4-0/"](http://snctln.com/2012/08/03/jmdns-and-android-4-0/)

```
private android.net.wifi.WifiManager.MulticastLock lock;
private android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
private JmDNS jmdns = null;
public  WifiManager wifi; 


private void setUp() 
    {
        
        WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
        int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
        String ipAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(ip);

        
         
        
        try {
            
            
            jmdns.create(_bindingAddress);
            ServiceInfo[] infos = jmdns.list("_afpovertcp._tcp.local.");
            for (int i=0; i < infos.length; i++) {
                 Log.i("Servic : ",infos[i].getName()+"");
//               notifyUser("\nServic : "+infos[i].getName()+"");
                
            }
            


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        
    }
```

your suggestion are appreciable

Answer (score 1):

My simple guess would be that it's trying to download data on the main thread. This is not possible from `Ice Cream Sandwich` and forward. Try to look at logcat while it runs on the phone, it should clearly show a warning/error message about it if it's the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can let it run via the main thread ala

```
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```