# Communication with jmdns.jar

Tags: bonjour, zeroconf, jmdns

I am using jmdns library to discover mDNS service advertise by other devices in network. I am using Android 4.2. I have downloaded demo application from jmdns official website and AndroidDnssdDiscoveryEclipse application is getting crashed at..

```
jmdns = JmDNS.create();
```

Here is the log..

```
07-25 18:15:57.343: W/dalvikvm(26977): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41526930)
07-25 18:16:11.703: D/dalvikvm(26977): Debugger has detached; object registry had 480 entries
07-25 18:16:11.703: I/dalvikvm(26977): ignoring registerObject request in thread=1
07-25 18:16:11.703: I/dalvikvm(26977): ignoring registerObject request in thread=1
07-25 18:16:11.726: E/AndroidRuntime(26977): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 18:16:11.726: E/AndroidRuntime(26977): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.jmdns.JmDNS
07-25 18:16:11.726: E/AndroidRuntime(26977):    at com.heeere.android.dnssdtuto.DnssdDiscovery.setUp(DnssdDiscovery.java:44)
07-25 18:16:11.726: E/AndroidRuntime(26977):    at com.heeere.android.dnssdtuto.DnssdDiscovery.access$0(DnssdDiscovery.java:38)
07-25 18:16:11.726: E/AndroidRuntime(26977):    at com.heeere.android.dnssdtuto.DnssdDiscovery$1.run(DnssdDiscovery.java:27)
07-25 18:16:11.726: E/AndroidRuntime(26977):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-25 18:16:11.726: E/AndroidRuntime(26977):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-25 18:16:11.726: E/AndroidRuntime(26977):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-25 18:16:11.726: E/AndroidRuntime(26977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
07-25 18:16:11.726: E/AndroidRuntime(26977):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 18:16:11.726: E/AndroidRuntime(26977):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-25 18:16:11.726: E/AndroidRuntime(26977):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
07-25 18:16:11.726: E/AndroidRuntime(26977):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-25 18:16:11.726: E/AndroidRuntime(26977):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 18:16:11.796: D/dalvikvm(26977): GC_CONCURRENT freed 237K, 13% free 2560K/2932K, paused 5ms+9ms, total 80ms
07-25 18:21:11.921: I/Process(26977): Sending signal. PID: 26977 SIG: 9
```

Here ([jmdns.jar not working on android 4.0 or later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563950/jmdns-jar-not-working-on-android-4-0-or-later)), it is mentioned that jmdns.jar does not work with Android 4.0 or later but I have used ZeroConf Browser (uses jmdns) on my device and works perfectly.

While debugging application I have found that my application can not find jmdns.jar file. I have not done anything to jmdns.jar file accept I have removed original jmdns.jar file(1kb) from application directory and in place of it I have put jmdns.jar file(200kb) which comes along with download.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
jmsdn-3.4.1.jar downloaded from SourceForge.net was compiled not for Dalvik vm (Android).

I solved dowloading source files from SourceForge.net and rebuild jmdns.jar to use with Android projets.